# Há alguma palavra para indicar uma rua que é somente para pedestres?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Gostava de usar algum termo que indique que uma rua é usada somente por pedestres. Talvez uma palavra semelhante ao termo *pedestrianised* em inglês.

Por exemplo, a Carnaby Street é descrita da seguinte forma pelo Wikipedia:

> Carnaby Street is a pedestrianised shopping street in Soho in the City of Westminster.

Entretanto, a Rua Augusta, em Lisboa, é descrita da seguinte forma:

> A Rua Augusta é uma famosa rua da baixa de Lisboa, em Portugal.

Somente pelo texto, não dá para saber se a rua é uma via para carros também ou não. Há algum termo para este tipo de rua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há o termo ***pedonal***, que, segundo o Houaiss, é um termo de Portugal, para lugares em que só podem andar pessoas, como *A rua pedonal cheia com jacarandás*. O Priberam dá como seu sinônimo ***pedestre***, como *rua pedestre de compras de Lisboa*; o termo talvez soe esquisito, mas, após poucos usos, torna-se normal, e é mais fácil de alguém que nunca havia ouvido entender.

Comment: Obrigadíssimo! Imaginei que seria uma pergunta sem resposta; que bom que perguntei e descobri esses termos.

Comment: @Sidney, Deus salve o Google.

Comment: Se eu usar "pedonal" aqui no Brasil, é quase certo que ninguém vai entender.  E, se eu explicar o que é, vão dizer que sou pedante porque estou a usar palavras desconhecidas.  Melhor dizer "rua de/para pedestres.

Comment: @Centaurus, eu provavelmente usaria *para pedestres* também. Uma preposiçãozinha não mata ninguém :)

Comment: @Centaurus, se começarmos a reduzir nosso vocabulário para agradar os outros a situação piorará. Eu falo naturalmente, usando as palavras que se encaixam melhor. Se alguém não perceber, o máximo que faço por elas é explicar.

Comment: @Sidney  Há uma diferença entre "tentar agradar **aos** outros"  e "ser pedante ou pernóstico".  No caso acima, não se trata de reduzir o seu vocabulário, mas evitar em conversas, o uso de palavras que você leu uma vez na vida e que provavelmente são desconhecidas por noventa e nove por cento da população.  A propósito, quantas vezes você ouviu a palavra "pedonal"?

Comment: Entendo. Mas estou considerando a situação em que você aprendeu uma palavra e a incorporou, de forma que agora você a usa para expressar de forma mais precisa o que quer. Acho que apenas soará pedante se, na conversa, você está tentando soar inteligente em vez de comunicar. Na experiência é perceptível a diferença.